# Какие библиотеки использовать для построения математических графиков на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, поиск-библиотек, график, визуализация

Мне нужны библиотеки или фреймворки на Python для построения математических графиков.

Например, у меня будет функция `2x^2+12x+2=0`, мне нужно построить этот график. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Практически все графические библиотеки в Python так или иначе используют [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/index.html) или являются надстройкой/расширением `matplotlib`. Например [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial.html), [bokeh](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/first_steps.html), [plotly](https://plotly.com/python/plotly-fundamentals/).

Также существует модуль для **аналитической** работы с формулами - [SymPy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/index.html), который также умеет чертить графики функций. Причем эти функции можно задавать как строки и парсить их.

Вот рабочий пример:

```
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import standard_transformations,implicit_multiplication_application
from sympy.plotting import plot

transformations = (standard_transformations + (implicit_multiplication_application,))

x = symbols('x')
formula_str = '2x^2+12x+2'
f1 = parse_expr(formula_str.replace('^', '**'), transformations=transformations)
f2 = -x**2
plot(f1, f2)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Библиотека `matplotlib` - подойдет лучше всего
[Документация](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.html)

Comment: Пожалуйста, опишите в ответе, почему Вы считаете, что `matplotlib` подойдёт лучше всего. Ещё очень хотелось бы увидеть минимальный пример того, как работать с этой библиотекой. Если в будущем название библиотеки или ссылка на документацию изменятся, то Ваш ответ станет бесполезен. Улучшить его Вы можете, нажав кнопку [edit]

Answer (score 0):

[Seaborn](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn)

Не хуже того же matplotlib

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]